# IE8 not respecting basic CSS rule

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a fixed footer on my [website](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/) and in order to create space between it and the main contents I gave the latter a bottom margin. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

The rule I used for this is

```
div#wrap>div:last-child{ 
margin-bottom:45px;
}
```

However, IE8 does not seem to respect this (very basic!) CSS rule as shown below.

[image]

Insofar as IE8 provides any errors/warnings whatsoever, it doesn't mention anything about this rule being problematic. Increasing the `margin-bottom` has no effect so the rule seems to be completely ignored. Does anybody understand why? And what is a sound workaround for this?

Comment: `:last-child` not supported in IE8.  Although `:first-child` is.

Comment: Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild

Comment: can't you add `padding-bottom:45px;` to the container?

Comment: @SetSailMedia: ...of course. Great, that's it! I was a little anxious about the footer moving up but it doesn't. Now let's all pray that IE8 will soon disappear altogether with Windows XP no longer being maintained...

Answer (score 0):

:last-child is a `css3` selector and will not be applied in ie8 if used.

First alternate solution(not recommended)

```
:first-child+(all the tags until the end) //:first-child+div+div+td+....
{
margin-bottom:45px;
}
```

Option 2(Recommended)
Give a class to the last child and add your css styling

Comment: the right answer was already given in the comments. Since the html is generated by PHP, I don't know what'll be the `last-child` in advance. Therefore your option 2 is not quite as good replacing the `last-child{margin...` by container`{padding-bottom...`